# Concatenating text and a number in place of control name

Tags: controls, concatenation, picturebox

I am back programming from a long hiatus. I know I have done this before but can't figure it out at the moment.

I have a series of picture boxes which are enumerated (pic1, pic2, pic3, etc...). I want to make them visible based on a random number. I need to do something like the following:

(pic[random]).Visible = true;     Where the random number becomes the enumeration.

I didn't find anything online quite like what i was having trouble with and I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What language are you programming in? Does the enumeration need to persist? Do you enumerate all the pictures up front? I' a little confused how to help.

Comment: Sorry. C# is the language. Yes all the picture boxes are already named. I simply need to be able to use a random number to choose a specific picture box. I know I can do this with a Case but it will be very lengthy.

Comment: As in if you have 6 pictures, get a random number (say three) and then retrieve pic3?

Comment: No, the picture is already in the box. I would need to take that number 3 and have it do the following: pic3.Visible = true;   I have many picture boxes so I really want to find a simple way to just take the random number and use it to select the right picture box.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to use a `Dictionary` object.

You would build the dictionary as

```
Dictionary<int,PictureObject> picDictionary = new Dictionary<int,PictureObject>();
picDictionary.Add(1,pic1);
picDictionary.Add(2,pic2);
...etc.
```

and then set pictures to visible as.

```
int randomNumber = MyRandomNumberGenerator();
picDictionary[randomNumber].Visible = true;
```

Comment: That worked. Great trick, I have never made a dictionary before. Thank you so much.